# Missing argument warnings with function

Tags: php, mysql

I have built a function to handle part of my login system specifically.

This is the error I'm being shot down by:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for dbclass::logcon(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\login.php on line 105 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\assets\includes\functions.php on line 10

This is the code in question

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $user     = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //To ensure that none of the fields are blank when submitting the form if
    if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

        $user     = stripslashes($user);
        $password = stripslashes($password);

        $db1 = new dbclass();
        $db1->openDB();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$user}' AND password='{$password}'";


        $result = $db1->logcon($sql);
        $row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

And finally, my function.

```
function logcon($user, $password) {

    $esc_user     = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, $user);
    $esc_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, $password);
    $sql          = "select * all from users where username  ='{$user}' AND password='{$password}";
    $result       = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);

    if ($result) {
        $numofrows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->conn);
        return $numofrows;
    } else
        $this->error_msg = "could not connect!";
    return false;

}
```

As you can see, I have passed the 2 arguments. So confusion reins admittedly.

Comment: Uhm no, I can't see that. `$result=$db1->logcon($sql);` looks like one ergument to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got:

```
function logcon($user, $password )
```

but

```
$result=$db1->logcon($sql);
```

Comment: Please also consider pointing OP to the other mistakes and vulnerabilities in his/her code instead of simply going for the low hanging fruit.

Comment: *low hanging fruit* I love it! I think you should include preparing, and using [`->num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead. (Yes I know affected rows does a different thing, but if the query is different, it'll mess up your code)